# Schedule a shutdown that can't be easily cancelled

Tags: windows, shutdown

`shutdown -s -t 300` can easily be cancelled later by `shutdown -a`

Is there a way to schedule a shutdown such that it cannot (easily) be cancelled?

Comment: Arguably, therapy and/or a better social life would be better solutions to the overall problem.  But those would be off-topic...

Comment: There are programs and features within Windows that force children to only have access to their user profile for certain amounts of time each day.  Those systems work because, those children, don't have the ability to change the permissions that allow or disallow behavior.  So unless your willing to ALWAYS have no choice in the matter, you should just learn to have some will power, anything I could suggest could just easily be bypassed by you.

Comment: It's not possible. Any solution that can be implemented by an Administrator can be undone by an Administrator.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I installed "timekpr" for my kids.  It will log out the account after the hour that was set.
I also added a script to shutdown the computer when nobody was logged for the past X minutes.

Instead of doing a 'shutdown', do a 'poweroff' and add it to your cron script.

Further - if you want to remember most of what you learn - you have to repeat it and sleep on it!  That's part of the brain rules ;-).

Comment: I edited the question to remove the context as this was distracting.  The comments above relate to the original context of using `shutdown -t` as a way of limiting internet surfing time.

Comment: You really need an operational definition for not easily cancelled.  Something that would be difficult for one person could be trivial for another.  Something that would require 5 minutes of involved procedure might be easy, but still a deterrent, and what would deter you might not deter someone else (questions here should apply to a broad swath of users, not just you, personally).  Something that requires another person (permissions, password, knowledge), might be trivial for them but impossible for anyone else.  (cont'd)

Comment: I suspect there could be solutions to the underlying problem, but asking for them is likely to be overly broad (brainstorming).   I'll vote to reopen, though, because the answer to the narrow question you asked is probably "no".

Comment: What would happen if you schedule the shutdown via the hardware? BIOS/UEFI on many motherboards have had a scheduled time the computer would be operational for, turning it on and off. because the "power" switch (hardware) is capable of initiating a proper (windows) shutdown, although I have never seen that.  Why do you have extended timing on your shutdown command? I think mine is to fast to try and stop it with another shutdown command.

Comment: Loosely related: [How to hide a code from myself until a specified time?](http://superuser.com/q/619152/150988)

Comment: Is the requirement to shut off the computer, or is it to cut off Internet access?  You might want to look into modem/router-based solutions, where you configure your Internet box to deny net access during certain hours.